# How to use same component in React multiple time but with different CSS on different pages

Tags: reactjs

I have created a separate file of some data and importing in different files. With the map function, I am printing this data in the

tag. But want to use this data on different pages with different CSS like in some pages I need color changes or different font size. No event requires. Just want to print data of same component but with different CSS on every page.

```
    `const Truck = [
    {
        icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
        text: "Door pick-up and delivery",
    },
    {
        icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
        text: "Heavy weight shipments",
    },
    {
        icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
        text: "Same day delivery in city limits",
    },
]
export default Truck`................

Map function

}`export const UlServicesItems = () => {
    return (
        <div id="UlMarginTop">
            {Truck.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <div id="txt">
                        <li key={index} className="iconTruck">{item.icon}</li>
                        <li key={index} className='newId'>{item.text}</li>
                    </div>

                )
            })}
        </div>`enter code here`
    )
```

Comment: Use props to the component to tell it what kind of style it should have

Answer (score 2):

You could define some sort of theme and pass it as props to your component.

First create some CSS classes.

```css
.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.big-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

In your parent component, define themes and pass it as props to the components.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Card from "./Card";

export default function App() {
  const theme = {
    backgroundclass: "bg-green",
    textclass: "big-text"
  };

  const theme2 = {
    backgroundclass: "bg-red",
    textclass: "big-text"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card theme={theme} />
      <Card theme={theme2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your child component, use the theme prop and set the values to the corresponding elements.

```js
export default function Card({theme}) {
  return (
    <div className={theme.backgroundclass}>
      <p className={theme.textclass}>hello</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-pond-cgo4s?file=/src/App.js:0-361)